# Uncaught TypeError: reading 'map'

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm fetching a json from an `API` in visual Studio Community to a `ReactJS` app in Visual Studio Code.

After following some documentation, I configured the Program.cs of the API, only adding an `AddCors()`

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:3000/");
        });
});
```

And this is how my React app is:

```
class ClientComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cliente: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: myHeaders
    };

    
    fetch("https://localhost:7079/cliente/listarClientes", requestOptions)
    .then(response =>response.json())
    .then(
      result =>{
        console.log(result.json)
      }
    )
    /*.then(
      result =>{
        this.setState({cliente:result})
      }
    ) */
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Clientes</h2>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Correo</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.cliente.map((cli) => (
              <tr key={cli.ID}>
                <td>{cli.ID}</td>
                <td>{cli.Nombre}</td>
                <td>{cli.Correo}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const element = <ClientComponent></ClientComponent>;
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(element);
```

So, my API is in Debugg mode, and this is the url of the json I'm trying to fetch:

https://localhost:7079/cliente/listarClientes

As you can see, I fetch the data of the right url, but I'm unable to show it in a `table`

And this is what it shows in console.log():

```
{"message":"Datos recuperados con exito","status":true,"data":[{"id":"1111","nombre":"Pedro","correo":"pedro@gmail.com"},{"id":"2222","nombre":"Marta","correo":"marta@gmail.com"},{"id":"24352345","nombre":"Juan","correo":"juan@bellavitis.com"},{"id":"3333","nombre":"Luis","correo":"luis@gmail.com"},{"id":"4444","nombre":"Carlos","correo":"carlos@gmail.com"},{"id":"5555","nombre":"juani","correo":"juani@gmail.com"},{"id":"6666","nombre":"francisco","correo":"francisco@gmail.com"}]}
```

But in my React app, I have a problem to `map()`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at ClientComponent.render (index.js:36:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19752:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19698:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21611:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

I also tried with Hooks but it is the same...

```
  const [repos, setRepos] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://localhost:7079/cliente/listarClientes`);
        setRepos(response.data);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

What should I do? I'm practising, since this is my first project that I try to connect an API with ReactJs app.

Answer (score 0):

```
 render() {
return (
  <div>
    {this.state.cliente.map((cliente) => (
      <p>{cliente}</p>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

}
}

export default ClientComponent;

You need to make sure that you are using the correct URL when fetching the JSON from your API. The URL you have in your code is currently https://localhost:7079/cliente/listarClientes, but this may not be the correct URL for your API. You should double-check with your API documentation to make sure that this is the correct URL for fetching the JSON data you need. Additionally, you may need to add additional headers to your request options object such as an Authorization header if required by your API.